# How to receive a JSON object with Rack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, sinatra, rack

I have a very simple Ruby Rack server, like:

```
app = Proc.new do |env| 
  req = Rack::Request.new(env).params
  p req.inspect 
  [200, { 'Content-Type' => 'text/plain' }, ['Some body']]
end 

Rack::Handler::Thin.run(app, :Port => 4001, :threaded => true)
```

Whenever I send a POST HTTP request to the server with an JSON object:

```
{ "session": {
"accountId": String,
"callId": String,
"from": Object,
"headers": Object,
"id": String,
"initialText": String,
"parameters": Object,
"timestamp": String,
"to": Object,
"userType": String } }
```

I receive nothing. I can detect the request received but can't get the data. The results at my console for `puts req.inspect` is something like:

```
"{}"
```

How am I supposed to get the data?

I tried to change that with something like:

```
request  = Rack::Request.new env
object   = JSON.parse request.body
puts JSON.pretty_generate(object)
```

But I'm getting the following warning:

```
!! Unexpected error while processing request: can't convert StringIO into String
```

Comment: What's an example of the JSON being sent?

Comment: nothing sent , JSON being received something like above example with session root

Comment: Ok it seems that i'm supposed to use something like : 

    msg = JSON.parse env['rack.input'].read

Then just use params in msg hash , at least it worked to me this way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
env['rack.input'].gets
```

This worked for me. I found that using curl or wget to test POST requests against a Rack (v1.4.1) server required using this code as a fallback to get the request body. POST requests out in the wild (e.g. GitHub WebHooks) didn't have this same problem.

Answer (score 7):

It seems that I'm supposed to use something like:

```
msg = JSON.parse env['rack.input'].read
```

Then just use `params` in the `msg` hash.

At least it worked for me this way.

Comment: If you look at env, you will find a pair like this: `"rack.input"=>#<Rack::Lint::InputWrapper:0x007fd293a085d0 @input=#<StringIO:0x007fd2939f1088>>,` that means you can it as an IO, so use `read` method on it.

Answer (score 0):

One more way to do that:

```
# ...
request  = Rack::Request.new env
object   = JSON.parse request.body.gets
# ...
```

See the documentation: [www.rubydoc.info/gems/rack/Rack/Lint/InputWrapper](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rack/Rack/Lint/InputWrapper)