# How to handle object from 'PUT' request in Rack

Tags: ruby, rack, minitest

In a basic Rack server how do I get data from a put request?

For example my test is like this:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'rack/test'
require_relative './myserver-rack'


class MyApp < Minitest::Test
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  def app
    App.new
  end

  def test_put
    put '/data/foo', 'my object'
    
  end
end
```

Then in my server Rack file I have this but I need to be able to get the `my object` data from the put request to pass to my method later:

```
...
 def call(env)
    mydata = "??" # need to put something here to get my data
    p = env['PATH_INFO']
    case env['REQUEST_METHOD']
    when 'PUT'
      put(p, mydata)
    end
 end
...
end
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707034/how-to-receive-a-json-object-with-rack

Comment: That was it, thank you!